# error C4430, C2143, and C2244 for a function in my template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-declaration

I'm trying to make a function that takes a templated type and adds it to the end of the list/array and I'm running into an error that I can't seem to find a way around. I'm new to templates so I'm not sure if it's a problem with how I'm using templates or something else.

Here is the relative portion of code that I have:

```
// MyArray.h

// insure that this header file is not included more than once
#pragma once
#ifndef MYARRAY_H_
#define MYARRAY_H_

template <class elemType>
class MyArray
{
private:
  int _size;        // number of elements the current instance is holding
  int _capacity;    // number of elements the current instance can hold
  int _top;         // Location of the top element (-1 means empty)
  elemType * list;  // ptr to the first element in the array

public:
// Ctors
    MyArray(); // default
    MyArray(int capacity); // initialize to capacity
    MyArray( MyArray & original); // copy constructor

// Dtor
    ~MyArray();

// METHODS
// Add
    // Takes an argument of the templated type and
    // adds it to the end of the list/array
    void Add(const elemType & elem);
};

// =============================================================================

/* ... */

// METHODS
// Add
    // Takes an argument of the templated type and
    // adds it to the end of the list/array
    template <class T>
    void MyArray<T>::Add(const elemType & elem)  // error C4430 and C2143
    {
        list[ _size + 1 ] = elem; // Place item on the bottom of the stack
    } // error C2244


#endif
```

And I'm getting these errors:

```
Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int               c:\...\myarray.h    80  1   Testing_Grounds
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'                                                      c:\...\myarray.h    80  1   Testing_Grounds
Error   3   error C2244: 'MyArray<elemType>::Add' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration  c:\...\myarray.h    83  1   Testing_Grounds
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your definition, `elemType` is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <class T>
 void MyArray<T>::Add(const elemType & elem)  // error C4430 and C2143
 {
   //...
 }
```

Here what is `elemType` (in the function parameter)? It should be `T`. Or `T` should be `elemType`.

```
template <class T>
void MyArray<T>::Add(const T & elem)  //fixed!
{
  //...
}
```

Note that the definition of the class template members should be in the header file itself, not in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: Wow! I knew it was going to be something small and overlooked. Thanks a ton! now I can finally get back to work!

Comment: I will! I'm waiting for it to let me, got my answer in mere minutes after posting so I still have to wait for about 5 minutes until I can :)

Answer (score 0):

In your header, you use `<class elemType>` and in the cpp you use `<class  T>`

In your cpp, change the `<class  T>` to `<class elemType>`, `MyArray<T>` to `MyArray<elemType>` and everything will be fine.